# How to Keep lable names for text box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)

In this plunker I want to keep lable names on top of textboxes. How can I keep lables for the textboxes.

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
 <input type="text" ng-model="item.rowId"> <input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
 <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
 <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style='margin-left:4px'></span></a>  
 <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="addParentRow(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to prevent changes on `rowId` element.
In that case just add `ng-disabled="true"` to that input:

`<input type="text" ng-model="item.rowId" ng-disabled="true">`

Comment: Nester what It will do

Comment: I Just want to keep a lable name on top of that textbox

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help u  
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aMLFE/25/)

**CSS**

```
label {display:block;}
textarea { display:block;}
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="title">Title: </label><textarea rows="5" id="title" name="title"></textarea>
```

Comment: I want to achieve the functionality like what Praveen suggested. and It should not repeat for each iteration